# call to a member function unreadNotification() on null

Tags: laravel, authentication, notifications

So here is the thing. This has been bugging me for a while and i cant seem to get a solid fix on this. I have 2 guards. one is admin and the other web. So i have multi auth setup.

I have setup the notification like so:

-Admin:

```
Auth::guard('admin')->user()->notify(new RoomStatusRoomboy($notifyroomnumber, $created_at_stamp));
```

-User (normal auth):

```
\auth()->guard('web')->user()->notify(new RoomStatusReception($notifyroomnumber, $created_at_stamp));
```

I am getting the results fine. But i have this code in my normal auths blade. this code is inside of one of the blade files which i use to display notifications:

```
{{\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::guard('admin')->user()->unreadNotifications()->count()}}
```

I am counting the number of notifications for admin auth inside of a web auth. so it will look for `App\Admin`. But the thing is i am getting `call to a member function unreadNotification() on null` error. and i think that it is because of the auth. I am trying to view this with the admin logged out. When i log in as admin on another tab and retry, it works. But with admin logged out, it does not work.

Please note that `{{\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::guard('admin')->user()->unreadNotifications()->count()}}` is inside of a view of normal auth and not admin. This is inside of a web logged auth.

Hope i am making sense here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is pretty obvious. The Auth facade will return null if there is no user currently authenticated.
So, I advise you had the auth middleware to your route or controller.

Comment: I have fixed the issue by sending the notification to a collection of user and admin and displaying it through who is authenticated. But thanks for the suggestion. Yes it was obvious of what was wrong.